# Сохранение введенных элементов

Tags: c++

Как мне сохранять элементы, введенные по одному в списке, а после каждого введенного вывести также заранее введенные элементы?

Т.е ввожу элемент 1, выводит тот же. Ввожу еще одну, но выводит 2 (вместе с предыдущим) и т.д. Я вот тут подумал для этого воспользоваться массивом, написал код, но тут что-то не то, он выводит только последний введенный элемент. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

Вот код:

```
int main()
{
    string x;
    string array[] = {x};
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        cout << "Enter: n";
        getline(cin, x);
        cout << endl;

        List L;       // Это список L, который уже создан до int main

        L.ElAdd(x);   // Добавление введенного элемента в Список   
        cout << endl;
        L.print();    // Вывод элементов списка
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно обявление списка L надо вынести за пределы цикла, иначе он будет создаваться в каждой итерации цикла и каждый раз будет пустой. Подправленный код:

```
int main()
{

    string x;

    string array[] = { x };
    List L;
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
    cout << "Enter: n";
    getline(cin, x);
    cout << endl;

    L.ElAdd(x);     // Добавление введенного элемента в Список   
    cout << endl;
    L.print();      // Вывод элементов списка
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```